# Am I supposed to instantiate my classes that extend DbContext?

Tags: entity-framework, entity, entity-framework-migrations

Using code-first migrations and Entity, the class

```
public partial class MyDb : DbContext
{
    public MyDb()
        : base("name=mydb")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<BannedIP> BannedIPs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<GameLog> GameLogs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<IP> IPs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Score> Scores { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating ( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder )
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<GameLog>()
            .Property(e => e.logText)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IP>()
            .HasMany(e => e.BannedIPs)
            .WithRequired(e => e.IP)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Score>()
            .Property(e => e.name)
            .IsUnicode(false);
    }
}
```

was generated to mirror my existing database. My question is why it generates a constructor

```
    public MyDb()
        : base("name=mydb")
    {
    }
```

Why would I need to make more than one instance of this class? Couldn't it be a static class since all I'm doing with it is making transactions on a single database? I'm just trying to figure out the reasoning behind it ...

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307295/username-impersonates-real-person

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DbContext tracks every entity it sees. This information will grow and grow if you reuse the same context for all operations and users. The generally recommended approach in ASP.NET is to use one instance of DbContext per request to prevent the thing growing so large that it brings your app pool crashing down.